# Sharepoint adding customcontrol to web-part error

Tags: sharepoint, user-controls, web-parts

I am new in Sharepoint. I have created customcontrol and added it to web-part. I have registered control:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="UserControls" TagName="FormContactUs"
Src="~/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/FormContactUs.ascx" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages"
Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<UserControls:FormContactUs runat="server" id="formContactUs" Mode="Colleague" />
```

But it returns error : "element 'FormContactUs' is unknown element. This can occur if there is a compilation error or the web.config file is missing "

Please any ideas where the issue can be.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the usercontrol like this:

```
<UserControls:FormContactUs runat="server" ID="formContactUs" Mode="Colleague" />
```

Happy coding!

Comment: http://blog.tentaclesoftware.com/archive/2010/07/21/95.aspx - This is amazing solution for similar problem guys!!!! It works for me!